# htaccess deny all files in all subdirs of a directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, access-control

I am working on a webpage that uses CKEditor for editing pages' text content and I have found out that although the listing of the DIRs is denied people can still open specific files directly (publicly) if they know exactly where those files reside thus they could change the content to whatever they want (a.k.a. hackers paradise)!

I am looking for an **htaccess solution** file placed in the root of my webpage (alongside the index.php) and **using mod_rewrite** (as I already have some rules in place with this specific syntax) in a style of:

```
RewriteCond
RewriteRule
```

Specifically, I just need to deny public access to all the files in all the directories and subdirectories in ./js/ckeditor (basically everything in and behind ckeditor directory)

I did search for the solution on the internet but all I could find was how to deny access to subdirectories, not all files in all the subdirectories of one directory.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^js/ckeditor - [F]`

Comment: @rtfm yes, this is the right answer - it works nicely exactly as expected, thank you (if you could post it as separate answer I would flag it as the solution)